# HighCharts-XRange Series: Unable to enable horizontal scroll bar

Tags: highcharts

For XRange chart in High Charts I need to show data for the hours of a single day, but the viewing window needs to be of 8 hours and the data for the remaining day should be viewable by scrolling horizontally.

I am unable to introduce such a scroll bar for my own data.
I have referred to other similar questions asked here including [this](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/) and also the HighCharts documentation [here](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/). But I can't find any specific example for the XRange series. I understand I need to import HighStock and enable the scroll bar:

```
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
        },
```

XRange charts are given on HighCharts here https://www.highcharts.com/demo/x-range and I tried the following with the given example: https://jsfiddle.net/291qyxf0/1/ but I do not see any horizontal scroll bar and the chart simply gets truncated.

Here's my attempt with data for a single date: http://jsfiddle.net/g4kn4u32/78/ with data for 1 hour and viewing window of half hour.

Comment: Although you have imported highstock, you are not using it in your example. highcharts initializes charts with `Highcharts.chart(...)` whereas highstock initializes with `Highcharts.stockChart(...)` After doing that and making sure highstock is imported before the modules, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/291qyxf0/6/

Comment: Note: You don't need to use `stockChart()` constructor. Just load Highstock instead of Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g4kn4u32/82/

Comment: How did I miss that. Thanks for the help!